# Helm: can't set mongodb root password from the values

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to install mongodb and set the root password

I've tried this:

```
helm install mongo bitnami/mongodb --set mongodbRootPassword=admin123
```

and this:

```
helm install mongo bitnami/mongodb -f mongo-values.yaml
```

while this is my values:

```
# cat mongo-values.yaml
mongodbRootPassword: admin123
```

But it looks like `mongodbRootPassword` is ignored in both cases. this is how i try to get my root password:

```
# kubectl get secret --namespace default mongo-mongodb -o jsonpath="{.data.mongodb-root-password}" | base64 --decode
TK0iwk8lue
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [docs](https://hub.helm.sh/charts/bitnami/mongodb) use `auth.rootPassword` instead of `mongodbRootPassword`. `mongodbRootPassword` is for mongodb from stable chart and not for mongodb from bitnami

```
helm install my-release \
--set auth.rootPassword=secretpassword,auth.username=my-user,auth.password=my-password,auth.database=my-database \
bitnami/mongodb
```

The above command sets the MongoDB root account password to `secretpassword`. Additionally, it creates a standard database user named `my-user`, with the password `my-password`, who has access to a database named `my-database`